# Creating a page that displays only once on a login

Tags: php, html, authentication

I'm developing a website that when a user/member logins into the website for the first time it shows a tutorial page, just like Twitter.

If anybody could point me in the right direction or even supply the code (If it's not too long) I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have to login to your website, you might want to add an extra field in your users table called something like 'inital_page_viewed' (default = false).

Once they login the first time and view this page, update this field to true. Only display the page if the field is set to false.

Cookies are a good idea for normal visitors, however if they clear their cookies and go back to the page they will get the 'tutorial page'.

Its worth bearing in mind the new EU cookie law as well, (not sure if this applies to your website). http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies.aspx

Comment: So if I go and add another field to my table called tutorial_page, then default = false, which I'll do. Then what would be the code to ensure to gets changed?

Comment: when they login, I assume you either save their userID or username to a session or cookie to remember their logged in? On the tutorial page, simply do a mysql (or similar) update to their row in the users table:

mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_users SET tutorial_page=1 WHERE user_id=" . mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_SESSION['user_id'])) . " LIMIT 1);

Then whenever they log in in the future check this value to make sure they have viewed the tutoral page. If they haven't just redirect them to it, otherwise forward them to the normal post-login page.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP to set a cookie on the tutorial page.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

If the cookie has already been sent have the user forwarded to the actual website instead of staying on the tutorial page.

e.g.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["tutorial"]))
header('Location: main.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but as Phil Cross, said if they clear there cookies they're going to return to that page on login.. :D